# Suppress the post from switching my TAB position

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to suppress the post action to switch my tab position to the first TAB.  I am calling an Ajax function which makes the unseen post, preventing the refresh/post from happening, thus staying on the tab that the user is in.  I created a test code to simulate this (I didn't use tabs for my test).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Click</title>
</head>
<script src="../../../Product/WebServer/Software/Page Format/Ajax_Submit.js"></script>
<body>
<p>Click on This!</p>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit Changes"/>


</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript Document Ajax Submit
$(function() {//Open function
$('#Submit').click (function(){ //Open select
alert("Submit button is being suppressed!");
doAjaxCode();
}); //Close select

function doAjaxCode(SubmitStatus) { //Open doAjaxCode
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index_phaseII_v02.html",
    data: "Nb_var97=" + SubmitStatus,
})
} //Close doAjaxCode

}); //Close function
```

This works as expected, no problems, wonderful!!!

Problem:

When I take this sample code and apply it to my actual code, it doesn't work?
It doesn't even display the alert msg?  By the way, yes I am including the following line to run
the script in my main html page:   any ideas as to what is happening?

Thank you,
Neil P

#### Update

Ok, I don't know why or partially know why, but doing this made it work!

`$('#Submit').click (function(){ //Open select` <------changed this line from this

to

`$('input').click (function(){ //Open select` <-------#Submit to input

The reason I say, I partially know, is because if the button's id is Submit like so,

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit Changes"/>
```

then, I expect it to work???? I know that now by doing input, it will work for all my buttons, but in the future if I only want to address a particular button by using its id attribute, then it will come in handy..

Can anyone comment?

Thanks.

Comment: do you get any error messages?  Are you including jQuery in your site?

Comment: yes Ben336 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  look below, its now working, but I still have an inquiry.

Comment: the 2 should not be different, unless you have multiple items on the page with the id Submit.  Also you probably want to have a submit button tag, not an input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know why or partially know why, but doing this made it work!

`$('#Submit').click (function(){ //Open select`   <------changed this line from this

to

`$('input').click (function(){ //Open select`  <-------#Submit to input

The reason I say, I partially know, is because if the button's id is Submit like so,

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit Changes"/>
```

then, I expect it to work????  I know that now by doing input, it will work for all my
buttons, but in the future if I only want to address a particular button by using its
id attribute, then it will come in handy..

Can anyone comment?

Thanks.

Comment: hey Neil, this should be an update to your question, not an answer.

Comment: I've added it to the question, please remove this answer.